# git diff displays tabs and whitespaces of the same length differently

Tags: git, vim

Noticed something strange:

Using vim, I replaced the indentation on a line of code from 3 tabs to 24 whitespaces. In vim, the code aligns with the above line, which still has 3 tabs.

But in 'git diff' console output, I'm seeing something like(ignore the actual width here) :

```
-          if (...)
+           if (...)
```

It's minor issue, but a bit curious.. So I'm picking the collective SO brain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how tabs work. They go to the next tabstop, which means the next multiple-of-8 column in the default settings.

If your line starts with 8 spaces, the next character will be in column 9. If it starts with a tab, the next character will be in column 9.

If it starts with a `+` and 8 spaces, the next character is in column 10 because the 8 spaces still take up 8 spaces.

If it starts with a `-` and a tab, the next character is in column 9 because the tab only takes up "however much space is left before the next multiple-of-8".

Tabs are terrible.